# Next.js parse data-type from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, next.js, node-postgres

I'm new to Next.js and I am currently following the official tutorial. To spice it up, I decided to run PostgreSQL locally instead of using the @vercel/postgres SDK used in the tutorial.
In the tutorial, they use the `sql` function of the SDK, which I have replaced by `pool.query()` from the node-postgres client.
For most queries, this works fine and I am able to communicate with my local PostgreSQL database.
However, I am having trouble adapting this code:

```
const data = await sql<Revenue>`SELECT * FROM revenue`;
```

What is it doing? From my understanding, `<Revenue>` is a type passed with the `sql` function, which I suppose is used to parse the data returned by @vercel/postgres.

How could I adapt my code to parse the `<Revenue>` data-type using node-postgres? Here is my current code:

```
const data = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM revenue`);
```

For reference, [here](https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/blob/main/dashboard/starter-example/app/lib/data.ts) is the code I am trying to adapt (line 24 in data.ts). The `<Revenue>` type is defined in definitions.ts and the database content is in placeholder-data.js

Thank you for your help!